# Meld syntax highlighting feature is disabled

Tags: gtk, meld

I have installed Meld 1.8.3, which runs fine except that syntax highlight and some other features are disabled. I haven't been able to find out why these options are disabled and how I can enable them.

[image: Preferences dialog box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hover your mouse over any of the disabled option it will tell you that these features require `python-gtksourceview2`. Just install that and the options will become available.